# Interpretation of a sample space problem

Tags: probability

$A, B$ and $C$ take turns in flipping a coin. The first one to get a head wins. The sample space of this experiment is as given:

$S = \{1, 01, 001, 0001, \dots ,\\0000\}$

Then how can I interpret the sample space? I cannot understand that $0000$ case in the sample space. Does it mean that none wins? If it means that, then should not it be excluded from $S$ and included in $S^c$?

Please help me by explaining this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last one doesn't make sense as written: four tails and then stop. Surely they are supposed to keep going. Was it actually supposed to be "$0000\ldots$", that is, an infinite sequence of all tails?

Comment: yes, it means an infinite sequence of all tails. But why is it included in S? I can't get it.

Comment: If this case weren't included, someone else might complain that the author had not considered what happens if the players only get tails. Answer: they just keep flipping the coin forever. But since we assign zero probability to that event, it has no impact on the calculations.

Comment: Oh, Thanks Sir. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

The sample space is indeed given by
$$S=\bigl\{0^k 1\bigm| k\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}\bigr\} \cup\{000\ldots\}\ .$$
Fate selects a point $\omega\in S$. The points $\omega=0^k1$ have a probability $p_k>0$, whereas the special point $\omega=000\ldots$ has probability $p_\infty=0$.